# Powershell Foreach loop in INI file

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am actually new in Powershell scripting with inni files and I need to create a foreach loop that allows me to get multiple variables.
Let me explain :
I have an INI files that contains severals groups (Active Directory groups), I need my powershell script to extract those groups that have names like (group1, group2, group3 and so on).

I tried this piece of code but nothing goes out.

```
$i=0
$query = $configfile.Domain.group.$i

ForEach($query in $configfile.Domain.group)
{
$i++

write-host $query.$i

}
```

Looks like i'm pretty bad, any advices ?

Comment: What is `$configfile`?

Comment: $configfile = Get-IniFile .\Variables.ini

Comment: This is the .ini file that store my variables

Comment: And where does `Get-IniFile` come from? And what does the contents of the ini file look like?

Comment: This function : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/

Comment: I can't show directrly my config file because it's pretty confidentials ^^, but it looks like this : [test]  and then the variable : domain=test.lan

Comment: then you can call $configfile.test.domain to get test.lan

Comment: So your actual file looks like `[Domain] group=group1 ...`?

Comment: Exactly, and the loop needs to be able to extract group1, group2 and so on

Comment: In that case you can remove the first two lines, and the `$i++` statement - `$query` is going to refer to the current group being iterated over inside the loop already

Comment: I want at least my command to give me group1 so that I can do the ++, but i don't know how to add the simple digit at the end

Comment: What do you need `++` for? `foreach(){}` will automatically move the loop forward

Comment: The [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/) also has an example of how to loop through the result from `Get-IniFile`.  See the part underneath _“Awesome. Now what?”_

Comment: Do you know any scripting languages or programming languages that use variables?

Comment: It may easier for us to help you if you could share an example ini file using those groups

Answer (score 2):

If your INI file looks anything like this:

```
[Groups]
group1=example
group2=example1
group3=group1
group4=example3
group5=group2
group6=example5
```

then you can use the function from [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/) like this:

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath) {
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath {
        "^\[(.+)\]" # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        "^(;.*)$" # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
        "(.+?)\s*=(.*)" # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}

# the data returned is a Hashtable where each entry is listed 
# under a certain section name. This data is UNORDERED by default
$data = Get-IniContent -filePath 'D:\Test\groups.ini'
```

Get all group names found in the ini file under section 'Groups'

```
$data['Groups'].Keys | ForEach-Object { $data['Groups'][$_]}
```

Output:

```
example
example5
group2
group1
example1
example3
```

Or get only certain group names that look like 'group' for instance

```
($data['Groups'].GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value -like 'group*' }).Value   
# or alternatively do:
# $data['Groups'].Keys | Where-Object { $data['Groups'][$_] -like 'group*' } | ForEach-Object { $data['Groups'][$_] }
```

Output:

```
group2
group1
```

If you want the found group names sorted, append `| Sort-Object`

Comment: Thanks ! I already find somthing to use, and it looks like what you just did.

Comment: Excellent answer, this works great. Though I'm a bit surprised you have to resort to regex, I mean there's no standard PowerShell object or function for `.ini` files? I thought `.ini` files were quite common

Comment: @BdR Thanks. No, parsing .ini files is not incorporated in PowerShell. This is just the part that reads/parses the ini file and is part of a module I wrote some time ago. Since then there are modules to be found on Github, but as of yet, PowerShell itself does not natively support it (probably never will)

Answer (score 1):

The $query in the loop is declaring a new variable which hides the variable declared outside the loop.

Without an example of the ini file, I can only guess, but you could try replacing the loop block with `write-host $query`.

This will at least show you what is going on.

Comment: The ini file looks like this : ```[Groups]
group1=example
group2=example1
group3=example2
group4=example3
group5=example4
group6=example5```